# Cambiar de posición el echo de mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Quisiera mandar a imprimir el resultado de un cuestionario pero el resultado me sale en la parte superior izquierda, pero lo tengo que mover el resultado arriba de la tabla

```
<?php


    include('conexion.php');
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');

    $uno1 = $_POST['1'];
    $uno2 = $_POST['2'];
    $uno3 = $_POST['3'];
    $uno4 = $_POST['4'];
    $uno5 = $_POST['5'];
    $uno6 = $_POST['6'];
    $uno7 = $_POST['7'];
    $uno8 = $_POST['8'];
    $uno9 = $_POST['9'];
    $uno10 = $_POST['10'];
    $uno11 = $_POST['11'];
    $uno12 = $_POST['12'];
    $uno13 = $_POST['13'];
    $uno14 = $_POST['14'];
    $uno15 = $_POST['15'];
    $uno16 = $_POST['16'];
    $uno17 = $_POST['17'];
    $uno18 = $_POST['18'];
    $uno19 = $_POST['19'];
    $uno20 = $_POST['20'];

    if($uno1 == '')
    {
        header('location=index.php');
    }
    else
    {
    $fecha = date("Y-m-d"); 

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Info (Fecha) VALUES ('$fecha')");

    $id = mysql_insert_id();

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Respuestas (Idinfo,Idtems,respuesta) VALUES ('$id','1','$uno1')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Respuestas (Idinfo,Idtems,respuesta) VALUES ('$id','2','$uno2')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Respuestas (Idinfo,Idtems,respuesta) VALUES ('$id','3','$uno3')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Respuestas (Idinfo,Idtems,respuesta) VALUES ('$id','4','$uno4')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Respuestas (Idinfo,Idtems,respuesta) VALUES ('$id','5','$uno5')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Respuestas (Idinfo,Idtems,respuesta) VALUES ('$id','6','$uno6')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Respuestas (Idinfo,Idtems,respuesta) VALUES ('$id','7','$uno7')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Respuestas (Idinfo,Idtems,respuesta) VALUES ('$id','8','$uno8')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Respuestas (Idinfo,Idtems,respuesta) VALUES ('$id','9','$uno9')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Respuestas (Idinfo,Idtems,respuesta) VALUES ('$id','10','$uno10')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Respuestas (Idinfo,Idtems,respuesta) VALUES ('$id','11','$uno11')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Respuestas (Idinfo,Idtems,respuesta) VALUES ('$id','12','$uno12')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Respuestas (Idinfo,Idtems,respuesta) VALUES ('$id','13','$uno13')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Respuestas (Idinfo,Idtems,respuesta) VALUES ('$id','14','$uno14')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Respuestas (Idinfo,Idtems,respuesta) VALUES ('$id','15','$uno15')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Respuestas (Idinfo,Idtems,respuesta) VALUES ('$id','16','$uno16')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Respuestas (Idinfo,Idtems,respuesta) VALUES ('$id','17','$uno17')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Respuestas (Idinfo,Idtems,respuesta) VALUES ('$id','18','$uno18')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Respuestas (Idinfo,Idtems,respuesta) VALUES ('$id','19','$uno19')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Respuestas (Idinfo,Idtems,respuesta) VALUES ('$id','20','$uno20')");


    $total = $uno1+$uno2+$uno3+$uno4+$uno5+$uno6+$uno7+$uno8+$uno9+$uno10+$uno11+$uno12+$uno13+$uno14+$uno15+$uno16+$uno17+$uno18+$uno19+$uno20;



    if($total < 36)
    {
    echo "Deficiente";

    }
    elseif($total < 62 && $total > 35)
    {
    echo "Bajo";
    }
    elseif($total < 88 && $total > 61)
    {
    echo "Intermedio";
    }
    elseif($total < 114 && $total > 87)
    {
    echo "Sobresaliente";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Alto";
    }
    }


?>

<html>
<head>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="contenedor" style="width:90%; margin: 0px auto;">
<br>
<br>
<center><h2> <br> <br>Anexo 1 </h2>
<h3>  Escala Médica de Empatía de Jefferson, en su versión al español </h3></center>
<br>
<br>
<br>
     <br>
   </p><br>

<div style="text-align:center;">
    <table class="egt" border=1 cellspacing=0 style="text" align="center">
        <tr>
          <th>Puntaje obtenido en la escala de empatía médica de Jefferson</th>
          <th>Nivel de empatía médica</th>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td align="center" color="#A9E2F3" >114-140</td>
            <td align="center">Alto</td>
           </tr>
              <tr>
               <td align="center">88-113</td>
               <td align="center">Sobresaliente</td>
              </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td align="center">62-87</td>
                    <td align="center">Intermedio</td>
              </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td align="center">36-61</td>
                    <td align="center">Bajo</td>
                   </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td align="center">20-35</td>
                        <td align="center" >Deficiente</td>
                        </tr>
     </table>
</div>


<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <p> Secretaría de Salud de Veracruz | Dirección de Atención Médica</p> 
  <a href="http://web.ssaver.gob.mx/seic/">Subdirección de Enseñanza, Investigación y Capacitación</a>
  <p>Departamento de Capacitación | Capacitación a Distancia</p>
  <p>Tel. (228) 1 41 17 00 ext. 3210, Av. Américas No. 426 Esq. Hernán Cortés <br>
Col. 2 de Abril, C.P. 91030, Xalapa, Ver. </p>
</footer>

 <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te sale arriba de la tabla porque ahi lo estas mandando a imprimir, solo debes anidar tu codigo php en el html en la posicion que lo requieres, en este caso antes del table

Answer (score 0):

En los if anidados hacen falta agregar `==`

```
{ 
echo "Bajo"; 
} 
elseif($total == 61) { 
echo "Intermedio"; 
} 
elseif($total == 87) { echo "Sobresaliente"; } 
else { echo "Alto"; } }
```